# Strange behaviour of PIC18F14K50 EUSART. it only works when the logic analyzer probe is connected

Tags: pic, uart

I'm using a [PIC18F14K50](https://www.microchip.com/content/dam/mchp/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/40001350F.pdf) and a RS485 bus transceiver ([ADM3485](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADM3483_3485_3488_3490_3491.pdf)) to communicate with a Modbus RTU sensor network. the PCB is not designed by me, (and it has a very foolish/compact design, so it makes it very hard to debug or probe) and it seems troublesome. aside from that, the PIC18F14K50 has no debugging capability on its own.

The problem is, that while the logic analyzer is connected to monitor the RS485 signals, the device works fine but when I disconnect the probes, it won't.

**Some clues:**

- the UART packet, when the probes are connected, is correct. everything works as expected.
  [image]
- leaving the logic analyzer's ground, or disconnecting it (after disconnecting the probes) won't change anything. so I guess the probes themselves make the system work somehow.
- the simulations in software, work perfectly.
- the other devices on the network work fine and find themselves. they are from PIC18 family too.
- the twisted wire length is under 1m (I'm working on my bench) and there is a 120R and 150R terminator resistors at both ends. there are 1K pull-up/pull-down resistors for the RS485 lines.
- the microcontrollers on the bus, use same uart software library. however, the only difference for the DUT (the problematic PIC18F14K50 I'm talking about) is that the RX pin of the EUSART is multiplexed with ADC. I had problems before with analog pins of the PIC18, when used as inputs.

The part of schematic as provided by designer:

[image]

The uart library, sets the IO like this:

```
ANSELHbits.ANS11  = 0; //disable the analog input on RX
void uart_init(uint32_t sysCLK, uint32_t baudRate)
{
  uint16_t baudTemp = (sysCLK/(64*baudRate))-1;
  SPBRGH1_REG  = (uint8_t)(baudTemp>>8);
  SPBRG1_REG   = (uint8_t)(baudTemp);
  TXSTA1bits.SYNC    = 0;
  RX1_INPUT;

  DISABLE_ANSEL_RX1;

  TXSTA1bits.TXEN      = 1;
  RCSTA1bits.CREN      = 1;
  RCSTA1bits.SPEN      = 1;
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is the logic analyzer connected when it works? On the PIC side of transceiver, or RS485 side? Isn't it a problem when the PIC uses 3.3V and transceiver uses 5V?

Comment: I won't say this _is_ the problem, but a very suspicious circumstance is that U2 is a 3.3V part running off of a 5V rail.  It's absolutely not rated for 5V operation, so there's very little chance that it'll have inputs designed to operate with a 3.3V-powered device.  It's probably just barely failing to work without the logic analyzer connected, and just barely clinging to functionality with.  If you can modify the board, I suggest powering U2 from 3.3V and report back on how things work.

Comment: Why are you running your ADM3485 off a 5V rail? It's only rated for max 3.6V operation, and you even have a 3.3V rail which you're using for the PIC!

Comment: @brhans yes it seems it's the problem. despite the fact the datasheet mentions an absolute maximum rating of 7v.

Comment: @TimWescott  Can I change it to a 5V version, e.g. MAX485? the MAX485V is 5V version, and the minimum input voltage HI of the chip, is 2V. so it would work with 3.3V level of the PIC. but I don't know if the RX (which is 5V because of the MAX supply)

Comment: The 'Absolute Maximum Ratings' of any parameter in any IC's datasheet *is not an operating spec*! Read the paragraph of text right next to those ratings and you find "This is a stress rating only; functional operation of the device at these or any other conditions above those indicated in the operational section of this specification is not implied." What those ratings tell you is that the IC probably won't die and let all its magic smoke out if it's exposed to those conditions - not that it'll actually work.

Comment: It looks like the PIC is not tolerant to voltages above VDD.  So -- no.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like common mode voltage problem, unless something went wrong with the termination.
Wire up grounds of connected nodes, then try without 120R & 150R, under 1m distance.